# Risk in creating a string domain

Tags: postgresql

In an effort to more easily migrate from Visual Basic to plpgsql I'd like to create a string as a domain in Postgres. Is there any inherent risk in doing so?

```
CREATE domain string AS TEXT;
```

I ask because of some c process or perhaps string is reserved?

Comment: I don't think there is any risk, but why would that making migration from SQL Server easier? It doesn't have a type `string`

Comment: Good point. I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: converting a Visual Basic program to a PL/pgSQL function requires a substantial change in the code to begin with (if not a total rewrite). Replacing "string" with "text" seems quite negligible in that context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create create a domain/type as a work around  but I caution against this

All future upgrades have to maintain this new datatype that added no new feature only overhead.

Converting Access/MSSql SQL queries and VB scripts to PLpg/SQL is a complete rewrite there is no way around that..

There are enough subtle/major difference between MS implementation of SQL and every other implementation to make it not work with any other database at all.

Only the most simplest queries will can be reused

```
Select * from sometable
```

but MS typically generates

```
Select * from [schema].[table]
```

Comment: Great answer. Keep it up!